# How to change Python version within IPython in anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython, anaconda

since tensorflow only works in python 3.5.2, my default IPython env in Anaconda invoke Python 3.6 which can't import tensorflow. Does anyone know how to change that? Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an environment that installs Python 3.5. See here: https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html

To summarize

```
conda create --name tenflow python=3.5 tensorflow ipython
```

Then, on Mac or Linux

```
source activate tenflow
```

or on Windows

```
activate tenflow
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Anaconda 4.2.0, which installs python3.5.
https://repo.continuum.io/archive/index.html

Comment: Why recommend using out-of-date software when Anaconda has a built-in way to handle this?